# Is it possible to auto archive cards?

Tags: trello

Is there any time-limit-setting you can set on a card so that it automatically gets archived after an amount of time or after a specific date?

If not it would be nice to have that option I think, either as an own option, an option in combination with due date or as a property on a list.

Answer (score 3):

Not currently, though you can at least now archive cards in bulk.
The [Trell blog](http://blog.trello.com/) has more details.